# When Returning Json results from a Controller

Tags: model-view-controller, json, viewdata

Can ViewData["SOME VALUE"] be returned also?  If not, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default json actionresult only serializes the model. But it's no problem to write your own implementation to serialize viewdata as well. You could download the source from codeplex and look at the default implementation and just rewrite that.